# C#, Split List<Class> into List<List<Class>> (group)

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of classes and how to split, group them?

```
class CLA 
{
    string GroupName;
    double Class;
    double Value;
}

...

public List<List<CLA>> Dividr (List<CLA> a)
{
    List<List<CLA> Clist = new List<List<CLA>>();
    Clist.Addrange(...) //Here 
    returnn Clist;
}
```

As for dividing, it would be split by it's properties, `GroupName`, Class.

Example, if elements have same `GroupName` and Class it will be one List<>.

Comment: @GiladGreen, well no, i dont have much experience with linq

Comment: `var grouped = myList.GroupBy(g => new { g.GroupName, g.Class })`

Comment: @DagvanorovLkhagvajav - still it is best to show what you have tried

Comment: Read on Linq GroupBy and show some minimum research effort...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `GroupBy`. Then, as you want an inner list and not `IEnumerable` use `ToList()` for each group:

```
List<CLA> data = new List<CLA>();
var result = data.GroupBy(item => new { item.GroupName, item.Class })
                    .Select(group => group.ToList()).ToList();
```

Unless for specific reasons consider returning `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CLA>>` instead - shame to already execute the query if not yet needed:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(item => new { item.GroupName, item.Class })
                    .Select(group => group);
```